# Python Selenium Clear Chrome Cookies

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to clear my chrome cookies, but i can't click a button: [BUTTON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExvsZ.png)

```
import os
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver

opt = Options()
opt.add_argument("start-maximized")
executable_path = r'chromedriver'
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = executable_path

global driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\SAMSUNG\Desktop\chromedriver', options=opt)
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com")
driver.get("chrome://settings/clearBrowserData")
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#clearBrowsingDataConfirm').click()
```

Comment: I don't see an attempt at sending a click in your posted code.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel i just edited it, still can't find the element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes form the chained shadowroots that doesn't allow for the element to be found:
[image]

```
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com")
driver.get("chrome://settings/clearBrowserData")
time.sleep(5)

javaScript = "document.querySelector('settings-ui').shadowRoot.querySelector('settings-main').shadowRoot.querySelector('settings-basic-page').shadowRoot.querySelector('settings-section > settings-privacy-page').shadowRoot.querySelector('settings-clear-browsing-data-dialog').shadowRoot.querySelector('#clearBrowsingDataDialog').querySelector('#clearBrowsingDataConfirm').click()"
driver.execute_script(javaScript)
```